# How can I create a secret message app using the square code method?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a secret message app, such that a text:

```
"If man was meant to stay on the ground, god would have given us roots."
```

is normalized to:

```
"ifmanwasmeanttostayonthegroundgodwouldhavegivenusroots"
```

And the normalised text forms a rectangle (​r x c​) where ​c​ is the number of columns and ​r​ is the number of rows such that ​c >= r​ and ​c - r <= 1​,

So for instance the normalized text is 54 characters long, dictating a rectangle with ​c = 8​ and ​r = 7​:

```
"ifmanwas"
"meanttos"
"tayonthe"
"groundgo"
"dwouldha"
"vegivenu"
"sroots "
```

Then the coded message is obtained by reading down the columns going left to right

```
"imtgdvsfearwermayoogoanouuiontnnlvtwttddesaohghnsseoau"
```

and further split to

```
"imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau"
```

The resulting cypher text for a non perfect rectangle can only have a single whitespace for the last rows.

```
"imtgdvs"
"fearwer"
"mayoogo"
"anouuio"
"ntnnlvt"
"wttddes"
"aohghn "
"sseoau "
```

This what I have done so far, I could only get my normalised text, but I am doing something wrong to convert it to a rectangle and to get a cypher text out of it.

```js
const output = document.querySelector('#encoded_rectangle');
const encodedChunks = document.querySelector('#encoded_chunks');
const text = document.querySelector('#normalized_text');
const string = document.querySelector('#message');
const error = document.querySelector('#alert');

const encodeMessage = () => {
  let message = string.value;

  function wordCount() {
    return message.split(" ").length;
  }

  if (wordCount < 2 || message.length < 50) {
    error.innerHTML = "Invalid message, Input more than one word and at Least 50 characters!";
    return false;
  }

  function normaliseMessage() {
    return message.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "").toLowerCase();
  }

  function rectangleSize() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(normaliseMessage.length));
  }

  function splitRegEx() {
    return new RegExp(".{1," + rectangleSize + "}", "g");
  }

  function plaintextSegments() {
    return normaliseMessage.match(splitRegEx);
  }

  function ciphertext() {
    var columns = [],
      currentLetter, currentSegment;
    var i, j;

    for (let i = 0; i < rectangleSize; i++) {
      columns.push([]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < plaintextSegments.length; i++) {
      currentSegment = plaintextSegments[i];

      for (j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
        currentLetter = currentSegment[j];
        columns[j].push(currentLetter);
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
      columns[i] = columns[i].join("");
    }

    return columns.join("");
  }

  function normalizeCipherText() {
    return ciphertext.match(splitRegEx).join(" ");
  }

  text.innerHTML = plaintextSegments();
  encodedChunks.innerHTML = ciphertext();
  output.innerHTML = normalizeCipherText();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type your secret message" id="message">
  <p id="alert"></p>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="encodeMessage()">Encode message</button>
</form>
<div class="box">
  <h3>Normalised Text</h3>
  <p id="normalized_text"></p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h3>Encoded Chunks</h3>
  <p id="encoded_chunks">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h3>Encoded Rectangle</h3>
  <p id="encoded_rectangle">
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code is constructed of very short methods.
Usually I'd consider a good practice, but in this case I think it just made the code less readable.

Additionally, I have to say that the HTML part wasn't necessary in terms of solving the issue - which was clearly Javascript/algorithm related.

This is my solution, which can be modified to match your context:

```js
const input = "If man was meant to stay on the ground, god would have given us roots.";
const normalizedInput = input.replace(/[^\w]/g, "").toLowerCase();
const length = normalizedInput.length;
const cols = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(length));
const rows = Math.ceil(length / cols);

var cypherText = "";

for (let i = 0; i < cols; i ++) { 
  for (let j = i; j < normalizedInput.length; j += cols) {
    cypherText += normalizedInput[j];
  }
  cypherText += '\n';
}

console.log(cypherText);
```

Comment: Is this method symmetric?

Comment: @deblocker What do you mean by *symmetric*?

Comment: From this solution how can I form a rectangle out of my normalizedInput before encoding?

Comment: @Chioma I'm not sure I understand your question :/

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with

```js
const output = document.querySelector('#encoded_rectangle');
const encodedChunks = document.querySelector('#encoded_chunks');
const text = document.querySelector('#normalized_text');
const string = document.querySelector('#message');
const error = document.querySelector('#alert');

const encodeMessage = () => {
    let message = string.value;

    var normalisedText = message.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
    var textCount = normalisedText.length;
    if (textCount < 50) {
        console.log("Invalid message, Input more than one word and at Least 50 characters!");
        return false;
    }
    var higest = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(textCount));
    
    var lowest = Math.ceil(textCount/higest);
    var rect = [];
    var coded = [];
    var innerObj = {};
    var resulting = "";
    
    rect = rectangleSize(higest,lowest,normalisedText);
    //read text from top-down i hotago!!!   
    coded = readFromTopDown(rect, higest);
    coded.forEach(co => {
        resulting += co.trim();
    });
    //nwa idi sharp, nice logic
    console.log("Normalized: " + normalisedText);
    console.log("Count: " + textCount);
    console.log(rect);
    console.log(coded);
    console.log("Resulting: " + resulting);    

    function rectangleSize(higest, lowest, normalise) {
        var rect = [];
        var startIndex = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < lowest; i++){        
            if(i !== 0)
                startIndex += higest;
            if(normalise.substring(startIndex, startIndex + higest).length == higest){
                rect.push(normalise.substring(startIndex, startIndex + higest))
            }else{
                //get the remainder as spaces
                var spaces = higest - normalise.substring(startIndex, startIndex + higest).length;
                var textI = normalise.substring(startIndex, startIndex + higest);
                var str = textI + new Array(spaces + 1).join(' ');
                rect.push(str);
            }
        }
        return rect;
    }

    function readFromTopDown(rect, higest) { 
        var coded = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < higest; i++){   
            var textMain = "";     
            rect.forEach(re => {
                textMain += re.substring(i, i+1);
            });
            coded.push(textMain);
        }
        return coded;
    }

}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type your secret message" id="message">
    <p id="alert"></p>
    <button type="button" class="button" onclick="encodeMessage()">Encode message</button>
</form>
<div class="box">
    <h3>Normalised Text</h3>
    <p id="normalized_text"></p>
</div>
    
<div class="box">
    <h3>Encoded Chunks</h3>
    <p id="encoded_chunks"></p>
</div>
    
<div class="box">
    <h3>Encoded Rectangle</h3>
    <p id="encoded_rectangle"></p>
</div>
```

Try and see